# How can I control the height of an Option element in Webkit?

Tags: html, css, forms

This seems really simple but I can't even find something telling me that it's not *possible*, let alone how to do it.

I've got a page that uses expanded/multiple `select`s, and I can't seem to control the height of the options. They look really snug. In Firefox, CSS values for `option` in `height` and `line-height` both seem to have the desired effect, as does `padding`, but not in Chrome 8 or Safari 5. Am I missing something? Here's a sample of my code. I've put in anything that could affect the option in case there's some overriding value that I'm missing.

```css
body, input, select, checkbox { 
  font-family:'Avenir Lt Std',AppleGothic,'century gothic',Verdana,sans-serif; 
  font-size: 15px; 
  font-weight:200; 
  line-height: 18px; 
}

input, select { 
  color:#4c2a18; 
  border: 1px solid #cfc8b4; 
  background-color:#ffffff; 
  -moz-border-radius: 0; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 0; 
  border-radius: 0;
  margin:0; 
}

option { 
  height: 35px; 
  padding:5px; 
  line-height: 35px; 
}
```

```html
<select size="5">
  <option value="">This is option 1</option>
  <option value="">Option 2</option>
  <option value="">Just trying to show how the line height thing works.</option>
</select>
```

You can view it in action [here](http://bensaufley.com/test/select.php).

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but I think this is likely impossible in Chrome. The `select` element (and, of course, its children `option` elements) are under the control of the underlying OS, rather than the browser. That it works at all in other browsers surprises me. You could use a styled, and JavaScript controlled, `ul` (or `ol`) to achieve a styled select-type element.

Comment: I can style the `select` element in Chrome, and add `padding` and such there.

Comment: I always forget that 'Enter' submits the comment. Anyway I've considered the `ul` route but it just seems unnecessary when the `select` does a perfectly adequate job, except for cramming all the things too close together. I'm trying to figure out why it doesn't always look crammed - if there's something farther up the hierarchy that's causing this, or what.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is not possible in Chrome, according to [the electric toolbox](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-optgroup-option-css-chrome/):

> **Setting padding on an optgroup or
>   option has no effect in Chrome** so you
>   cannot control the amount of
>   indentation. You can set the padding
>   of a select as a whole in Chrome (as
>   you can with IE8) but it looks really
>   weird. Unlike IE8 you can click
>   anywhere in the select to open it even
>   if it has padding.

Comment: @Ben Saufley, if you want a customized form control, you'll need to either: 1. roll your own, b. use a pre-built lib, iii. just live with the default.

Comment: @zzzzBov - So I've heard. Though I can do pretty much everything I need to without involving JS. This was a small aesthetic problem I was hoping to solve simply.

Comment: @Ben Saufley, Select elements tend not to be used as often as they're a bit ugly, you can perform the same choice using radio buttons, and with a little bit of styling you can turn a set of radio buttons/labels into something that works very similarly to a select element, while actually being skinnable.

Comment: @zzzzBov I hadn't thought of that. That's an interesting idea. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben Saufley, and if you need "multiselect" use checkboxes instead.

Comment: I almost didn't upvote this because of how stupid it is to not support styling the option element. Even though it's bad news, thanks for informing us. Now I need to go and make an entirely separate control to work with something I'm trying to do in AngularJS just so I can style it. Anyway... +1!