# Styling for option values in a HTML select drop-down doesn't work in Chrome & Safari

Tags: html, css, html-select

The inline CSS styling for an option value in a html drop-down list does not work on Chrome and Safari, but does seem to work in Firefox and IE.

Snippet of the HTML code:

```html
<option style="color:#4f5652;background:#f0f0ef;hite-space:nowrap;-webkit-appearance:button;text-overflow:ellipsis; padding:5px 4px 3px 4px;border-bottom:1px solid green" value="project">Project</option>
```

Comment: provide some more code and elaborate the problem What exactly do you mean by "Does not work" ?

Comment: take look for the url below on firefox and on chrome and see the difference: http://64.202.124.112/~cedro/en/ENERGY-EFFICIENCY/Internal-Lighting/Bassil-Fleihan-Institute    (look on the drop down menu in the right : projects navigation)

Comment: white-space instead of hite-space, but not work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`color` style works fine in `<option>` elements on Windows 7 with current versions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE, and Opera, as well as on Mac with Firefox; but appears to be a no-op on Mac with Chrome and Safari. Seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer - you can not do that in Webkit based browsers. I.e. about `padding` take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4749864/1499781)

To overcome your problem you can change your `<select>` to a list `<ul>` and style its' `<li>` items. That will work in every browser guaranteed.

Comment: Well... it is an idea... but how to make <li>s to show and hide on <ul> clicks... simulating indeed the <select> behavour.

Comment: @ElPiter you can use some minimal JS/jQuery for that

Comment: @ZoltanToth, good piece of advice. That is what I finally did and I think it had a nice looking :)

Comment: This is a great method, but you do lose the ability to select by typing and tabing between fields.

Comment: So basically it looks like NOT using `<select>` and `<option>`, but **CSS based dropdown** is the only option to make it, such as: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783353/creating-a-dropdown-list-item-menu-with-css-only)

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use this

```
select {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      -moz-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: This will hide the arrow from the dropdown, making GUI non-user-friendly...

Comment: Ok we can add the arrows by using CSS after before property

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="form_action.asp">
Select your favorite car:
<select name="carlist">
  <option style="color:#4f5652;background:#f0f0ef;hite-space:nowrap;-webkit- appearance:button;text-overflow:ellipsis; padding:5px 4px 3px 4px;border-bottom:1px solid green" value="volvo">Volvo XC90</option>
  <option style="color:#4f5652;background:#f0f0ef;hite-space:nowrap;-webkit-appearance:button;text-overflow:ellipsis; padding:5px 4px 3px 4px;border-bottom:1px solid green" value="saab">Saab 95</option>
  <option style="color:#4f5652;background:#f0f0ef;hite-space:nowrap;-webkit-appearance:button;text-overflow:ellipsis; padding:5px 4px 3px 4px;border-bottom:1px solid green" value="mercedes">Mercedes SLK</option>
  <option style="color:#4f5652;background:#f0f0ef;hite-space:nowrap;-webkit-appearance:button;text-overflow:ellipsis; padding:5px 4px 3px 4px;border-bottom:1px solid green" value="audi">Audi TT</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<p>Choose a car, and click the "Submit" button to send input to the server.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

as we can see in:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_value.asp

Comment: Thank you. , on Chrome Browser, Just taken the background css , not the border issue.

Comment: No luck on OSX with Chrome.

Comment: Also on Windows, no luck with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for `padding` workaround:

- You can use `height` for top and bottom.
- For `padding-left` you can use `text-indent`.

CSS:

```
select {
    height: 45px;
    text-indent: 5px;
}
```

If you really need to use `select` dropdown, otherwise you can use `ul` and `li` element as suggested by others.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to replicate this in Chrome on jsfiddle. You can apply the styles to `select`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aaronmacy/3uv8D/

Comment: @MouhamadOunayssi-DIGITALITS Maybe I'm misunderstanding you. I just added an example to my answer. Is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thank u for your replay , i understand your example, my problem was on the option tag into the select tag