# Text gets cut when using <select>

Tags: css

Although I'm using the same CSS for both `<input>` and `<select>`, text in `<select>` gets cut off, while the text in input is perfect. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

```css
input,
select {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 90%;
  height: 23px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: TheBoldFont;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #f26e7c;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="xxxxxxx">

<select>
  <option selected value="xxxxxxxxx">xxxxxxxx</option>
</select>
```

This is the result:

[image: illustration]

And this is what show up on hover in Developer tools of Google Chrome:

[image: chrome illustration]

Comment: It looks like the option itself has a padding, but I've found no way yet to change it. Setting line-height on the select also doesn't work.

Comment: It seems there is no answer (yet): [Select option padding not working in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681141/select-option-padding-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: @GolezTrol the OP seems to be talking about the text with the `select` element not the `option` elements

Comment: Set box-sizing to border-box and remove the height.

Comment: With IE this doesn't happen, other browsers adds 2px top padding to option for some reason

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Firstly remove the `height: 23px;` declaration.

Notice the the text is not cut anymore, however the elements have a greater height than what was needed.

To fix this, just change the padding to `padding: 6px 10px;`

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/08z1dgk3/)

```css
input,
select {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  font-family: TheBoldFont;
  font-size: 27px;
  color: #f26e7c;
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="xxxxxxx">

<select>
  <option selected value="xxxxxxxxx">xxxxxxxx</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yup - I've noticed, that for some unknown (yet) to me reason, fixing height on select element is a culprit here. Why is this happening would provide an answer to OP question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because the vertical padding is taking up space that was meant for the text. The text is cut because you've limited the height of the select to 23px.

Comment: Hm - sounds good, but why the same doesn't happen for `input` element? I got some feeling that something more is going on here.

Comment: Select elements are treated specially in some ways. Take a look a this article: https://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/

Answer (score 13):

Increase the line-height of the select by a few pixels.

This worked for me.

Changed this:

```
select {
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

To:

```
select {
    line-height: 17px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It happens because of the padding. Consider only using padding left and right, combined with min-height.

Comment: Removing the padding doesn't fix this problem.

Comment: Removing the padding + adding increasing height fixes the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could increase the height of the select item:

```
select{
   height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: What fi there is even more text?