# how can i increase Bootstrap combobox item height? is that possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

how can i increase Bootstrap combobox item height? is that possible?[image]
    
    
    
    
    1
    2
    3
    4

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a select box. Try using <li> to create a dropdown then control the <li> heights with css.

Comment: have you tried inspecting and giving a height in the css in browser.

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/kannankds/6g3zpth3/ check my fiddle

Comment: @ Jai we can increase the height of combobox but how to increase the item height or padding , ya i tried but no way plz hlp

Comment: Are you trying to add visual space between the text or make the text bigger...it's not clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681141/select-option-padding-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: @ Paulie_D iam trying ti increase the item text height , in image "dfgdfgdfg" is my text

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, simply change the top & bottom padding of the li element.

If you wanted to add an extra 10px to the top and bottom, add the following code to the li element:

```
style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;"
```

completed it would look like this:

```
<li style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;">
```

You could also create a custom CSS class to do this, would you be interested in this? It would involve changing your css file. If you would like to do this let me know and I will explain how to. Then the final result would look something like this:

```
<li class="whateveryounametheclass">
```

Good luck!

Comment: its not ul li its a combo box plz check my image

Comment: Could you send me the html code for the combobox? As far as I am aware bootstrap's dropdown is comprised of a list?

Comment: I looked at your jsfiddle, you are not using a bootstrap component. Rather use a bootstrap dropdown, then edit it in the way that I said.