# How to set the height of an option element in Chrome without Javascript?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, select

Neither

```
option {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

nor

```
option {
    height: 30px;
}
```

nor

```
option {
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

works. Can that be real at the end of 2015? If it really does not work however, how can I do that with VanillaJS ?

Comment: Unfortunately Chrome does not support the styling of `option` tags yet! (Except for background and font colors) You can do some clever stuff with `ul li` tags though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681141/select-option-padding-not-working-in-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, sorry. Whilst you can style the `<select>` element, you can't style `<option>` elements in Chrome (other than a few properties on the font - note currently you can't style the weight either)