# Bootstrap input and select padding-left cross browser issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I wish the padding input and select fields were left aligned.
In my form I overwritten bootstrap form-group-lg in this way

```css
    .form-group-lg .form-control {
       letter-spacing: normal;
       text-indent: 0.25em;
       border-radius: 2px;
       color: #555555;
       font-size: 14px;
       line-height: 1.42857;
       min-height: 38px;
       height: 58px;
    }
    .form-group-lg select.form-control {
       height: 58px;
       line-height: 58px;
       padding-left 9px; /* force alignament with firefox, fail in IE e Chrome */
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
          <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
          <select class="form-control" name="City" required="">
            <option>City</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately I noticed that if I try to force the padding-left in select field to align with that of the input field is displayed differently in each browser.

See the example with different browser
[EXAMPLE](http://www.bootply.com/zxLlMwVOCW)

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: native elements are paint, you can try this for chrome, but it takes away the carets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681141/select-option-padding-not-working-in-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `text-indent` property instead of `padding-left` (it will work on all browsers(tested on chrome and firefox)):

see your example:

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.form-group-lg .form-control {
  /*padding: 10px 16px;*/
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-indent: 0.25em;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #555555;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857;
  min-height: 38px;
  height: 58px;
}
.form-group-lg select.form-control {
  height: 58px;
  line-height: 58px;
  text-indent: 29px; // use this instead of padding-left
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <select class="form-control" name="City" required="">
          <option>City</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```