# How to give the padding for option with css only

Tags: html, css

How we can give the padding for option in select box or height ?
like this :

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: 500+ rep and no [mcve]? What do you mean by padding? That the options have the same size?

Comment: @mplungjan it is their only question, to be fair. But yes.

Comment: Like the option that are opening on after click on select box i want give the padding for that

Comment: As in this duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681141/select-option-padding-not-working-in-chrome

Comment: i dont want any jquery and java script

Comment: HTML default <select> cannot be styled. You should try using this https://select2.github.io/ custom select plugin. You can style as you want.

Comment: Not exist a W3C specification about styling select options. If you want style a select-option box you have to build from scratch your ouw select box. Or use one like select2.github.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you  cannot add custom style to Select input element since they are render by User agents (Browsers). You can use some plugin to render select element so that you can customize as you wish.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add custom style to Select input element since they are render by User agents (Browsers). You can use some plugin to render select element so that you can customize as you wish.