# CSS Attribute selection not working in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, attributes

Quick question. I've tried to search, but could not find anything. Could also be because I use the wrong keywords for search.

Anyways, this is my problem:

I'm hiding certain elements on my webpage using css like this:

```
.selectBox option[value='6']{
    display:none;
}
```

Works fine on my windows pc, but Safari v8.0.6 on mac will not use the css.
Are there any workarounds? I could add a new class and hide based on class, but I would like to do this using either 'value' or 'label' attribute

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qdsq5v70/

Comment: Do you have some JSFiddle for testing?

Comment: Are you sure it's the selector failing? Some browsers, from memory, don't - for whatever reason - allow `<option>` elements to be hidden. For testing p purposes it might be worth giving the element an `id`, and using that as the selector.

Comment: Here is fiddle. Does not hide option 2 on Safari, but works for me on windows in firefox: https://jsfiddle.net/qdsq5v70/

Comment: I agree with David Toams, it looks like the problem is with styling "option" not in selctor. See e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301729/styling-option-value-in-select-drop-down-html-not-work-on-chrome-safari

Comment: @DavidThomas: You might be right. But how would I hide these using css then? Do I have to use javascript to hide them?

Comment: You have now one hint, what to search - we identify you problem. Styling select is always a big pain :) You can e.g. change <select> to <ul> and "simulate" select by JS - this will work in all browsers. But this is only my quick idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the short answer is No, it's not possible using CSS, safari doesn't allow styling the options, only the select container
([Styling option value in select drop down html not work on Chrome & Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301729/styling-option-value-in-select-drop-down-html-not-work-on-chrome-safari))

but you can remove and add options using javascript (of course you probably know that already)