# css Select-Option with margin-top

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu, html-select

I'm trying to make dropbox or comboBox with select-option

I want to put space between select and first child(option).

[image]

I tried

```
          <select>
            <option style={{ marginTop: "100px" }} value="Test">test</option>
            <option value="Test">test</option>
          </select>
```

But failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: With the default select element that a browser renders, you can't. Styling of those is very limited. You'd have to build your own instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only a few style attributes that can be applied to an  element.

This is because this type of element is an example of a "replaced element". They are OS-dependent and are not part of the HTML/browser. It cannot be styled via CSS.

Unfortunately, webkit browsers do not support styling of option tags yet.

you may find similar question here

1. [How to style a select tag's option element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887133/how-to-style-a-select-tags-option-element)
2. [Styling option value in select drop down html not work on Chrome & Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301729/styling-for-option-values-in-a-html-select-drop-down-doesnt-work-in-chrome-sa)

**The most widely used cross browser solution is to use ul li**

Hope that helps!!!!