# border, padding property of <option> in google chrome

Tags: css

The following CSS

```
.sbHolder option {
    border-bottom : 1px dotted #515151;
    outline   : none;
    display   : block;
    outline   : medium none;
    padding   : 5px 0 5px 3px;
}
```

Is working properly in mozilla but in chrome there is no padding / no border

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748875/how-can-i-control-the-height-of-an-option-element-in-webkit/4749864#4749864

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what @Mr. Alien wrote, There is no cross-browser way of styling `<option>` purely with CSS. You can take a quick look [here](http://adam.co/lab/jquery/customselect/) for a plugin or search for some others plugins which are more suitable for your needs.