# HTML Select (Drop Down) Working differently in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

There is an Select Element in a page, it working awesome in Firefox but very sick in Google Chrome..

**Firefox snap**

[image: Firefox Image]

**Google Chrome snap**

..
 [image: Google Chrome Image]

**HTML**

```
        <select id="dropDown" class="dropDown">
            <option>Design & Creative</option>
            <option>Share Point Developer</option>
            <option>Software Development Engineer</option>
            <option>Silverlight Developer</option>
            <option>Dot Net Developer</option>
            <option>Quality Assurance</option>
            <option>Mobile Application</option>
            <option>IT Sales</option>
        </select>
```

**CSS**

```
.dropDown {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 60px;
    width: 450px;
    background: #c03400;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #fff; 
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    display: block;
    clear: both;

}

.dropDown option {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    height: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #626262;
    background: #f5f3f3;
    outline: none;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: block;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}

.dropDown:hover, .dropDown:focus {
    background: #a62e01;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The size difference in Chrome is because of the height attribute.  You can't set the height of an option element in Google Chrome.  [How can I control the height of an Option element in Webkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748875/how-can-i-control-the-height-of-an-option-element-in-webkit)