# Why select options get padding in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this markup:

```
<div style="direction: rtl; text-align: right;">
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
            <label class="hidden-sm hidden-xs">بازه زمانی </label>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value="1">1 روز گذشته</option>
                <option value="2">2 روز گذشته</option>
                <option value="3" selected="selected">3 روز گذشته</option>
                <option value="4">1 هفته گذشته</option>
                <option value="5">2 هفته گذشته</option>
                <option value="6">1 ماه گذشته</option>
                <option value="0">تعیین زمان</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm using bootstrap v3.1.1. The problem is, when I see the page in Chrome, some options get padding:

[image]

[Here](http://www.bootply.com/m7lvIIdMIM) is a working demo. I tried to remove all padding and margins by css; But nothing changed. Do you have any idea, why it's happening?

Comment: I have Chrome 37 on Mac and I could not reproduce the issue. Looks fine here.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by setting `text-align` property for `<option>` elements:

```
.form-control option {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Seems line in Chrome `direction: rtl;` not align text properly and trying to recalculate it position as options changed their positions on show.

[updated demo](http://www.bootply.com/nLxPCHD4US)

Comment: Nothing changed. I tested it previously. But thank you.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry what browser do you use? Maybe this is browser specific? IE? Have you tried it on other browsers?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 m

Comment: @Javad_Amiry windows?

Comment: @Javad_Amiry I have tested on Ubuntu and Mac OS X. And everything is fine for me. My fix worked only under Ubuntu on latest Google Chrome. Under Mac OS X I don't see any problems in both versions. Seems like this is only windows problem. Anyway styling option elements for Google Chrome is bad idea as there is no cross-browser solution. More info you can find here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748875/how-can-i-control-the-height-of-an-option-element-in-webkit/4749864#4749864 What I can recommend you is to create your own select control using JavaScript or deal with what you have.