# how to increase height of select options

Tags: html, css

how to increase height of select options in select box?
[In this how to increase height of select options in select box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNZoG.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I control the height of an Option element in Webkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748875/how-can-i-control-the-height-of-an-option-element-in-webkit)

Comment: try padding instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748875/how-can-i-control-the-height-of-an-option-element-in-webkit                   I tried with this for size=1 it will wont work

Comment: Was to quick with my first comment (which I now deleted), and the answer is: You can't change the height of a select's options, but you can increase the font size, which will increase the height. If you only want to change height, you need to make a custom select/option with for example checkboxes or radio buttons

Comment: @AakashMartand No cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: one approach to achieve this is to construct select box using div tags and bind events to the elements and add effects during slidetoggle. you can get a better looking select options box by doing this .